# Matplotlib blitting does not update my canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an application that uses a matplotlib canvas that contains basically an imshow and some artists objects (e.g. ellipses) on top of it. The figure canvas is bounded to the following event sequence:

- right-button pick the artist object --> will change the face color of the artists
- left-button release --> will move the selected artists to the new position

To speed up the drawing, I have to use blitting. When I run the sequences of event, the ellipse that was selected to be moved is displayed in both its old and new coordinates in the canvas. This problem does not occur when I replace the blitting machinery by a `canvas.draw()`.

Would you have any idea of what I am doing wrong with the blitting ?

Here is a quick and dirty snippet that reproduces my problem (ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7, matplotlib 1.1.1rc).

```
import numpy
from pylab import figure, show
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

def on_pick_ellipse(event):

    if event.mouseevent.button == 3:
        ellipse = event.artist
        ellipse.set_facecolor((1,0,0))
        subplot.draw_artist(ellipse)
        fig.canvas.blit(subplot.bbox)

    return True

def on_move_ellipse(event):

    global ellipse

    if event.button == 3:
        return 

    if ellipse is not None :
        fig.canvas.restore_region(background)
        newCenter = (event.xdata, event.ydata)
        ellipse.center = newCenter
        ellipse.set_facecolor((0,0,1))
        subplot.draw_artist(ellipse)
        fig.canvas.blit(subplot.bbox)
        ellipse = None
        return True

ellipse = None

data = numpy.random.uniform(0,1,(640,256))

fig = figure()
subplot = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect="equal")
subplot.imshow(data.T)

background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(subplot.bbox)

ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(100,100), width=100, height=30, angle=30.0, picker=True)
ellipse.set_clip_box(subplot.bbox)
ellipse.set_alpha(0.7)
ellipse.set_facecolor((0,0,1))

subplot.add_artist(ellipse)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", on_pick_ellipse)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", on_move_ellipse)

show()
```

Thanks a lot

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The canvas has to be drawn once before calling `fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox`.

So with the following the above code works fine.

```
fig.canvas.draw()
background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(subplot.bbox)
```